# How to hide Minecraft chat?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you hide the chat? I have tried everything, it won't work. My Edition is Windows 10 and 1.18.31

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch Minecraft: Bedrock Edition for PC.
2. Load one of your games.
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> on your keyboard.
4. Go to “Chat Settings.”
5. Click on “Chat: Shown” once at the top-left corner.
6. Change the option to “Chat: Hidden.”